# Solve for y as a function of a real variable x given that $\dfrac{dy}{dx}=2\sqrt{y}$.

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

In [this](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/a/7984) answer, this question was asked:

"*Solve for y as a function of a real variable x given that the differential equation $\dfrac {dy}
   {dx}=2\sqrt{y}$ holds.*"

Now as was expected (by the answerer), I found the solution to be $y= (x+c)^2$. Now according to that answer, this solution is incorrect.

The correct solution is: either $y = 0$ or $y = \cases{ 0 & if  x $\le$ a \\ (x-a)^2 & if  x > a}$ for some real number $a$.

Now, an explanation as to why this is correct was provided there but I couldn't understand it.

So, can the forum members here solve the given DE and explain why the former solution is incorrect? Thanks.

Comment: $$\sqrt{(x+c)^2} = |x+c|\neq (x+c).$$

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio, can you elaborate please?

Comment: Through the above remark it is simple to check that $(x+c)^2$ is not a solution of $y'=2\sqrt{y}$. Since $\sqrt{y}$, where defined, is non-negative, every solution is weakly increasing.

Answer (score 3):

You can solve the DE by separation of variables

$$
\frac{dy}{dx} = 2y^{1/2} \implies\int y^{-1/2}dy = \int 2dx \implies y^{1/2} = x + C
$$

If $x + C < 0$ then $y$ is not a real solution, so the trivial solution is the only one that works in that case. If $x + C \geq 0$ then you may say that $y = (x+C)^2$. The solution you have presented is the same except $C$ has been labeled $-a$ instead.

Comment: So do you mean there is *no significance* attached with having ..$- a$ instead of ..$+ C$ in the solution (i.e the minus sign is not required?)?

Comment: this is the same what i have written!

Comment: You can call the constant whatever you'd like. If you use $c$ then going by the reasoning in my answer you would have $y = 0$ if $x< -c$ and $y = (x+c)^2$ if $x \geq -c$. So aesthetically, the conditions look a little bit cleaner if you choose to call the constant $-c$ instead of $c$, but it's not wrong as long as you stay internally consistent.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner I believe the OP was having trouble with the part after obtaining $y^{1/2}= x + c$ and determining why they cannot just square both sides. (Btw I was not the one who downvoted).

Comment: @wgrenard, I am sorry to ask you, but how you have taken $y<0$ if $x< -c $ ?

Comment: @math Could you elaborate? I’m not sure what you mean. If $x/leq -C$ then $y=0$. What do you mean by ‘Taken $y<0$?

Comment: @wgrenard. You are getting a solution $y= (x+C)^2$ for $x \ge -C $ that I understand. But how you are writing other part for $x < -C$ in your 3rd comment.